# What happens if debtor pays before enforcement hearing?

Tags: canada, small-claims-court, british-columbia

This is a hypothetical scenario.

I had an order which the debtor was not following. He paid me just before the enforcement hearing. What do I need to do to cancel the hearing, or should I attend and just say I was paid? For example what's the difference between a [notice of withdrawal](https://www2.gov.bc.ca/assets/gov/law-crime-and-justice/courthouse-services/court-files-records/court-forms/small-claims/scl019.pdf) and an [acknowledgment of payment](https://www2.gov.bc.ca/assets/gov/law-crime-and-justice/courthouse-services/court-files-records/court-forms/small-claims/scl800.pdf)? What is meant by "in full satisfaction"?

Also, the debtor paid me too much. He sent it by e-transfer with no explanation. Am I obligated to ask if this was a mistake?

Comment: Since you mention this is hypothetical, do you have any concerns that the transfer is illegitimate that should be addressed? "I oversent, just send me the excess and you can keep the rest" is a common line of many scams and Nigerian princes.

Comment: This does hypothetically look like a common scam. Hypothetically you would be wise to ask about it on the Money stackexchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do I need to do to cancel the hearing, or should I attend and
> just say I was paid?

Both options would be acceptable. The latter would probably be easier, faster, and provide a means to get prompt express court approval for your actions.

> For example what's the difference between a notice of withdrawal and
> an acknowledgment of payment?

Withdrawal means you cease your suit (often due to a settlement), acknowledgement of payment means you have been paid. You would acknowledge payment.

> What is meant by "in full satisfaction"?

This means that everything you are owed pursuant to court order has been paid in full.

> Am I obligated to ask if this was a mistake?

Probably not. But you are probably obligated to return the excess if asked for it within the statute of limitations for an unjust enrichment action, possibly with statutory interest.